# Unpacking generator which yields a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator, iterable-unpacking

I cannot understand the output of the following sample code:

```
def g1():
    d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
    yield d

for a,b,c in g1():
    print a,b,c
```

In Python 2.7.14, the above would print out

```
a c b
```

There are two interesting aspects of this behavior:

1. That it prints out `a c b` intead of the sorted `a b c`, which is supposed to be the case since we are talking about dictionary keys.
2. If you just define the dictionary without writing the generator `d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}`, and then `for a,b,c in d:`, this will be a valueError.

Comment: Dictionaries are not ordered in Python.

Comment: Not in Python 2.7, anyway. Keys are returned in insertion order as a CPython implementation detail in 3.6, and will be as a language guarantee starting in 3.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First point:** dicts simply aren't ordered in Python 2.7.  Don't rely on it until 3.7+.

**Second point:** The generator `g1()`, *when iterated*, yielded a dictionary.  The proposed alternative:

```
for a,b,c in d:
    ...
```

is apples to oranges, this is iterating the dictionary itself.  For an equivalent duck to unpack here, you'll need *an object which returns a dictionary when iterated*:

```
for a,b,c in [d]:
    ...
```

Comment: This is to say that `a,b,c = d` where `d` is a dictionary defined as above will be a legal statement which assigns `d`'s keys to variables `a`, `b`, and `c`. Looks like the behavior is similar if `d` is a list. This is a surprise to me.

Answer (score 1):

1.) In Python 2.7, dictionaries are unordered.

2.) `for a,b,c in d:` will give you an error because you're trying to unpack just the keys of the dictionary into three variables, which won't work. You could however do `for a, b in d.items()` as it returns a list of tuple pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Colin's answer pretty much answer your questions. But if you want to solve your first problem with unordered list, try using built in class `OrderedDict` under `collections` library.